# Could the Runtime Exception (column list_id does not exist) come from left join?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

In my Android Studio project I have implemented a database (managed by Room). In my Dao file, I have the following query which causes an error:

```
SELECT tab1.list_id, ... FROM  
            (SELECT list_id, ...  FROM list_table) AS tab1  
            LEFT JOIN  
            (SELECT list_id, ...  FROM list_table NATURAL JOIN product_table NATURAL JOIN list_product_table GROUP BY list_id) AS tab2  
            ON tab1.list_id = tab2.list_id  
            ORDER BY list_position ASC, tab1.list_id ASC;
```

The error says `` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '`list_id`' does not exist ``. The error points to the file, which was automatically created by Room.

```
...
return __db.getInvalidationTracker().createLiveData(new String[]{"list_table","product_table","list_product_table"}, false, new Callable<List<ShoppingListDisplayValues>>() {
      @Override
      public List<ShoppingListDisplayValues> call() throws Exception {
        final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
        try {
          final int _cursorIndexOfPosition = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "list_position");
          final int _cursorIndexOfId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "list_id");
          ...
```

To be more specific, the error points to the line:

```
final int _cursorIndexOfId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "list_id");
```

Now my question is, could this error result from the left join? The really weird thing is, that the code **works** on **some** devices and on other not. Would be really glad, if someone has an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after debugging a couple of hours I found the error and a solution.

### Error origin

The error lies in the Room persistence library. When using this library on devices with API lower than 27 (at least this is what I guess, since I tested 3 devices with different APIs), then an exception gets thrown **IF** you use a table prefix in your `SELECT` statement. By "table prefix" I mean for example the `tab1.` in `tab1.list_id`.

### The solution:

Just use an alias for the column which has a table prefix.
Instead of

`SELECT tab1.list_id, ... FROM`

write

`SELECT tab1.list_id AS list_id, ... FROM`